# How to separate admin and the front web theme in angular 5 project

Tags: angular, angular5

Currently working on an angular project for external customers and staff.
The customer facing side uses a different theme and staff facing side also uses a different theme.
I really don't know where to start and the approach to take.
I will prefer **not** using two spa apps.

Comment: What about create a NgModule for customer and another for staff and routing them in function of login?

Comment: @PedroArantes, that might work. So inside  separate ngModules i declare the themes for each module. Thanks, i will give it a try.

Comment: read this article about organizing angular applications, maybe it'll help you
https://medium.com/@michelestieven/organizing-angular-applications-f0510761d65a. Read about encapsulation, maybe helps you with your CSSs files: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html

Comment: Really great stuff, thank you @PedroArantes